# Getting undefined method 'parent'

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So i asked this question a while back before but i still cant seem to get this right . im trying to make my comment model make comments for both topics and posts. i just want Comments controller to be able to handle comments going to post or topic.

routes :

```
resources :topics, :posts do
     resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

Topic Model:

```
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment Model:

```
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :topic
```

Post:

```
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comments Controller :

```
def create

    if params[:post_id]
      @parent = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @parent.comments.new(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user

      if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Comment saved successfully."
        redirect_to [@parent.topic, @parent]
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Comment failed to save."
        redirect_to [@parent.topic, @parent]
      end
    elsif params[:topic_id]
      @parent = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
      @comment = @parent.comments.new(comment_params)
      @comment.user = current_user

      if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Comment saved successfully."
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Comment failed to save."
      end
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
```

comment/form.html

```
<%= form_for [@parent, @comment] do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body, class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a new comment" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Comment", class: 'btn btn-default pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

I keep getting `undefined local variable or method parent` when trying to go to my topic/show view
also how can i implement comments to show up on topic/post view

Comment: Why you want to redirect to post.topic(`redirect_to [@post.topic]`)?

Comment: @Sravan no I'm now getting " first argument in form cannot be nil or empty "

Comment: you haven't changed the redirect to yet, also change `@post to @parent.` @miguel

Comment: @Sravan sorry I forgot to fix in both topic and post. It's been corrected now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104620/discussion-between-miguel-angel-quintana-and-sravan).

Answer (score 0):

> undefined local variable or method parent

You need to change your **local variables** (`parent` & `comment`) to **instance variables** (`@parent` & `@comment`) in the controller action and as well in the view in order to use those in the view.

The below should work

```
<%= form_for [@parent, @comment] do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body, class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.text_field :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a new comment" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Submit Comment", class: 'btn btn-default pull-right' %>
<% end %>
```

Also I've noticed that there are two `@parent` & `@parant` variables defined in the controller action. If its a typo then correct it.

Comment: I have corrected the typo and changed the local variables and now im getting `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar problem, first arguement cannot be nil